# How to stop <br/> executing when value not empty

Tags: html, jsp

I have a table where I am printing values from a database like so

> Name
>  Age
>  Address

My code is the following, it only prints the value when it is not empty

```
<table class="table">
<tr><td class="td_header"><spring:message code="label.test"/></td></tr>
<tr><td>
    <c:if test="${not empty test.name}">
        <br/>${test.name}
    </c:if>
    <c:if test="${not empty tax.address2}">
        <br/>${tax.address2}
    </c:if>
</td></tr>
</table>
```

However I have a problem when it is empty the break line still gets out putted and I get output like this

> Name
>  Age 
>  
>  Addess2

How can i fix this?

Comment: There's no way that it outputs the <br/> Inspect the source code of the result.

Comment: It does, however the below solution using div's instead has worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `<div>`s instead of `<br />`:

```
<table class="table">
    <tr><td class="td_header"><spring:message code="label.test"/></tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>${test.name}</div>
            <div>${tax.address2}</div>
```

So even if this prints out an empty `<div></div>`, it doesn't occupy space. That's how `<div></div>`s are designed. `:)`

Comment: Basically OP reports a serious bug in JSP, but it's probably not really so. In any case, this doesn't answer that question.

Comment: @wvdz This is just a different approach. Even by mistake, if the OP is outputting everything. Or, I will do one thing, I will edit the answer and update in a different way, so that you can remove the downvote?

Comment: @wvdz Can you kindly check the answer.

Comment: @wvdz As the OP confirmed my answer works, can you kindly check the updated answer and let me know if there is any mistake, to correct it and remove your downvote.

Comment: This solution has solved my issue so it does answer my question

Comment: @user3520080 Please click on the tick mark next to my answer.

Comment: I agree you improved it, but the problem apparantly is that OP's `<c:if>` tag is not doing what it's supposed to do. Not the use of `<br/>`. Your solution may work for this small example, but what if we need a conditional on a larger block of html?

Comment: @wvdz I didn't say anything about `<c:if>` and I don't have any clue about it too. So your argument is not valid. Is it?

Comment: If you have no clue about what `<c:if>` is supposed to do, maybe you shouldn't answer questions about it.

Comment: @wvdz Well, I am not that dumb. What should I do so that you can remove the downvote?

Comment: I don't believe that OP is correctly describing what is happening, and as a result of that, I don't think there is a correct answer possible at this point.

Comment: @wvdz Agreed. Fine. What should I do, so that you remove your downvote? `:)` Simple question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96686/discussion-between-wvdz-and-praveen-kumar).

Comment: Guys found out what was the problem there was spaces in the "blank" value in the DB so thats why the `<c:if>` condition wasn't appearing to be working correctly. I just used Java - String trim() Method and it's working now although the div solution also did provide a solution.